# XFS inodes suddenly exhausted - but not because of IUsed going up

Tags: filesystems, redhat, xfs

I got an alert that IUse% on my XFS filesystem had suddenly jumped from 3% to 96% used.

An hour or so later, it went back to 3%.

During the problem:

```
# df -i /data
Filesystem                        Inodes    IUsed   IFree IUse% Mounted on
/dev/mapper/VolGroup01-LogVol01 57082000 54388657 2693343   96% /data
```

After resolution:

```
# df -i /data
Filesystem                          Inodes    IUsed      IFree IUse% Mounted on
/dev/mapper/VolGroup01-LogVol01 2621197920 54375585 2566822335    3% /data
```

Note that IUsed (column 3) stays almost exactly the same -- in both cases there are ~54 million inodes used.

But during the problem, the number of inodes (column 2) changes drastically - from 2.3 billion (2300 million) - down to 57 million.

What could cause this?

Comment: any fsck activity recently ?

Comment: shouldn't be, the machine's been up for weeks.

Comment: what about "df -h". maybe new big files were created under that mount and xfs decided it did not need that much inodes and trimmed the number.